# Lost bluetooth device. Connection log?

Tags: bluetooth, logging, xiaomi, bluetooth-audio, 8.0-oreo

I lost my bluetooth headset. If I knew the exact time my phone lost signal with it, I could be able to locate it. Is it possible to find this information if my phone is not rooted?

Android 8.0, Xiaomi Mi A1

Comment: Details would be in some database , in `/system`, which is not accessible without root